# The UI is confusing when you add a synonym tag and it disappears

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, tags, tag-synonyms

Late last year I started to suggest edits about `complex-analysis` and also related tags such like `holomorphic-functions`. I was not aware that `holomorphic-functions` was a synonym of `complex-analysis` until 5 days ago... I didn't know synonyms even existed.

Once the edit is approved, the `holomorphic-functions` tag disappears! I only see the `complex-analysis` tag -- not the `holomorphic-functions` tag **I added**.

This led me to believe I was helping to classify posts, but in reality, I was not. Can we have a small warning note after you add a tag that is a synonym (and that explicitly tells the user that the tag is practically useless because it's  "equivalent" to the more general tag, in this case `complex-analysis`; and after your edit is approved, only the `complex-analysis` tag will be displayed) of one already on the post?